# Get users SAMaccount name from Full name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of users full name that I'd like to get their SAMaccount name but when I run my code I get no results.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
$users = Get-Content C:\users\admin\Desktop\move.txt

foreach ($user in $users){
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "$user"} |Select-Object name, samaccountname
}
```

Comment: What exactly is in $users, is it domain\username?  Have you tried using Name -Like "$user"

Comment: $users is the users full name ie Jon Doe

Comment: Check your input file for trailing whitespace: $users = Get-Content C:\users\admin\Desktop\move.txt |% {$_.trim()}

Comment: No trailing white space but to be certain I added `|% {$_.trim()}` still no output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that $user is null inside the script block. Try to use double quotes instead of braces and put the variable in single quotes to make the valid query (name contain spaces):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$user'" | Select-Object name, samaccountname
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a powershell script that should work for you.  You'll want to go to the link to read the fine details, http://wbarena.com/2015/01/powershell-find-ad-user-full-name.html.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$aResults = @()
$List = Get-Content “.\List.txt”
ForEach($Item in $List){
$Item = $Item.Trim()
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter{displayName -like $Item -and SamAccountName -notlike “a-*” -and Enabled -eq $True} -Properties SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, telephoneNumber, mail
$hItemDetails = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FullName = $Item
UserName = $User.SamAccountName
Email = $User.mail
Tel = $User.telephoneNumber
}
#Add data to array
$aResults += $hItemDetails
}
$aResults | Export-CSV “.\Results.csv”
```

Answer (score 0):

Use first and last name separately.

```
foreach ($user in $users){
    $SplitName = -split $user
    Get-ADUser -Filter {(GivenName -eq $SplitName[0]) -and (Surname -eq $splitName[1])} |Select-Object name, samaccountname
}
```